# security leak about jni & ndk

Tags: java-native-interface

I have a variable

```java
int a = 10
```

Now I can access the `int a` variable from C++ code in jni

```cpp
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_org_lotka_ndk_hello_world_MyChangeActivity_myfunction4int(
    JNIEnv *env ,
    jobject obj){
jclass myjclass = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
jfieldID myjfield43 =  env->GetFieldID(myjclass, "a", "I") ;
env->SetIntField(obj, myjfield43, 100);
```

It means that I can access that segment of memory which `int a`  is declared and i can modify it.

Is there a way to access the others application variables and change them?

Comment: What do you mean by "other application"? Is it code running in the same JVM? a different JVM? The JNI is explicitly designed to bypass all security measures put in place by the JVM, so you can change anything you can get a reference to.

Answer (score 1):

JNI does two things here:

1. it allows you to write native code and call into that from Java code
2. it allows you to interact with the "Java world" of that process from within the native code.

Item #2 is really just a convenience function here, because native code can usually access/modify all memory of itself directly, so if #2 didn't exist, one could still search for the location of `a` and interact with it directly. It might be *quite a bit* trickier (as it'd require knowledge of JVM internals), but it's possible.

With that in mind, the question "is there a way to access the others application variables and change them" boils down to:

How can (native) processes interact with each others memory space?

The answer is a typical "it depends" with a heavy dose of "usually not":

The issue at hand here is called [memory protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection): Effectively all current general-purpose operating systems are quite restrictive in their memory protection:

By default a process can only access its own memory and can't access any other processes memory.

But there are ways around that. For example a process running under the User 0 (root) has wide permissions to access memory in all kinds of different ways (such as directly accessing `/dev/mem` which gives raw access to *all* memory on Linux).

But even those permissions are not absolute and can be restricted in various ways (capabilities are one way to "split up" the very coarse root permissions and give them out part-by-part and SE Linux is a system to harden systems by disallowing most access and only explicitly allowing required permissions on a granular level).

Since your question mentions the NDK: On Android the Dalvik runtime is **not** considered to be a security mechanism, so Dalvik code is exactly as well-trusted as native code. In other words: all relevant security mechanisms work equally on native code. For example by default each application will get a dedicated (Linux-level) user assigned to it with minimal permissions.

**tl;dr** Most processes won't be able to see into or modify other processes, but there are exceptions, mostly related to superuser/root/system processes.

Comment: Excellent answer! One addition: on rooted phones you can use the [Frida framework](https://frida.re/docs/android/) to mess with applications that do not belong to you

Comment: @Botje: That's a good example, but I feel that my answer is already a bit too long for my taste, so I'd rather not get into too many details/examples like this. Rooting generally is just an example of weakening the protecting that's enabled in Android by default by allowing an "escape hatch" (i.e. root and specifically user applications with root privileges).